# Pdf is rendered with white pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am sending from my back-end pdf which works fine. I tried to open it in the browser directly (localhost:8843/documents/2/?access_token=123) 
But when I am opening it with JS, it loads only white pages without content. Eventhough the size of the pdf is the same, but it is empty...
I tried to open those pdf even in my back end server and it works ok... so there must be some error at front end.

```
const getPdf = (id) => {
    $.ajax({
        url: proxy + "documents/" + id,
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'bearer ' + localStorage.access_token},
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
          var blob=new Blob([data]);
          var link=document.querySelector(".pdf-link");
          link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          link.download="document.pdf";
        },
        error: function(error){
            alert(error);
        }
      });
}
```